# Map Reduce AWS Lambda & SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce, amazon-sqs, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function which spawns up a number of worker Lambda functions and each worker function posts to an SQS queue if there is any error.

There is a UI which long-polls the SQS queue for any errors. My problem is that how do I know when the processing is completed?

Since the first Lambda function (which spawns the worker Lambda functions) runs asynchronously, that is, it splits the data across the worker Lambda functions and then returns/finishes. I need to have an ability to be able to figure out when the processing is completed.

The reason why I'm only posting the errors to the SQS queue and not success is because if I have 10,000 objects to process and there are 9,000 successes, I would have to do quite many `ReceiveMessages` (an SQS API call to retrieve items from the SQS queue) in the UI/client side (probably around 900 calls if I specify the maximum number of messages to receive as 10 per call. You cannot retrieve more than 10 messages from the queue per a call.)

**How can I overcome this design issue?**

I'm using API Gateway, AWS Lambda and Dynamo DB (feel free to suggest any other Amazon/AWS service that could make this easier to get the job done.)